# Azure SignalR Service Upstream to Multiple Functions / Hubs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

I have the following services implemented on Azure:

- 1x Azure SignalR Service (Serverless) `ASRS`
- 2x Azure Functions (Serverless) `HubFuncDown` & `HubFuncUp`

On the `ASRS` I have defined TWO UpStream URLs, one to `HubFuncDown` Azure Function and the other to `HubFuncUp`. Using the URL pattern defined in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/concept-upstream):

[image]

`HubFuncDown` Contains the following method which instructs the device app to disable itself:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(DisableDevice))]
public async Task DisableDevice([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string deviceId, ILogger logger) {
    await Clients.User(deviceId).SendAsync(DisableDeviceTarget, new NewMessage(invocationContext, deviceId));
}
```

And `HubFuncUp` Contains the following method:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(DeviceDisabled))]
public async Task DeviceDisabled([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string deviceId, ILogger logger) {
        // .. Updates DBContext, sends alerts etc
}
```

I'm trying to tell `HubFuncUp` that this client is now in a disabled state, the code to do that on the (UWP) client is:

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .WithUrl("https://hubfuncup.azurewebsites.net/api", options => {
       options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Auth();
})
.ConfigureLogging(logging => {
    logging.AddProvider(new SerilogLoggerProvider());
    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
})
.WithAutomaticReconnect(new RetryPolicy())
.Build();
```

And to tell `HubFuncUp` of the state:

```
await connection.InvokeAsync("UpdateDeviceState", new DisabledDeviceMessage { DeviceId = 123, State = States.Disabled });
```

But each time I'm receiving a 404 Error from the call to `InvokeAsync("UpdateDeviceState"..)`. It seems no matter what I do I cannot connect the one `ASRS` to two Azure Functions using multiple Upstream URLs.

Am I correct in thinking I need to utilise a seperate Azure SignalR Service (which doubles my cost) or can I connect the two Functions to the one SignalR Service via routing on the Upstream URLs?

Comment: The interim solution for now is to use a seperate `ASRS` for each function. The client connects to both `ASRS`, listens for messages from `HubFuncDown` and responds to the second `ASRS` which routes the response to the `HubFuncUp` function.